# Android Studio and mediaPlayer

Tags: android-studio

I am developing a simple app in that my video is playing proper. but now  I want to give "thank" message after finishing my video
How can I do this?

MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.video);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_Play);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
        player.start();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.lenovo.play.app.VideoPlay"));
        }
    });
}
```

and Second VideoPlay.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
    view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String url = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    view.start();

    int duration = view.getDuration();



}
```

Comment: post your code what have done?

Comment: add code you have tried. Otherwise we cant help you

Comment: i have no done anything except to play video and get confused how to know video is finished

Comment: final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.video);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_Play);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
            player.start();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.lenovo.play.app.VideoPlay"));
            }
        });

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String url = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video;
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        view.start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener then add your message to onCompletion method:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
   //message
}
```